# Проблема с размерами div-ов

Tags: css, html

Имеется код. Не могу понять почему div-ы имеют отступ снизу и сбоку. Красный получается чуть больше и между синими промежуток. Подскажите, а то идей нет.

```html
<html>
    <head>
<style>

.videoContainer {
             display: inline-block;
             background-color: #0066b3;
                position: relative;
                width: 100px;
                height: 125px;
                margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
                padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
            }
            .videoContainer video {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
       
            #local {
             background-color: #ff0000;
                margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
                padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
            }

</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="local">
         <div class="videoContainer">
            <video id="localVideo"  oncontextmenu="return false;"></video>
        </div>
          <div class="videoContainer">
            <video id="localVideo"  oncontextmenu="return false;"></video>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: необходимо добавить font-size: 0; для #local http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/fg0hwk1g/ http://xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/pozitsionirovanie/inline-block-margins

Answer (score 2):

Знаю два варианта, использовать свойство `font-size: 0;` для блока `<div id="local">`, который является родительским, или убрать отступы и пробелы между дочерними блоками внутри и записать код в одну строку.

И еще. Не используйте одинаковые идентификаторы для повторяющихся элементов. У вас должен быть только один элемент `#localVideo` внутри документа.